# Why removeEventListener on the new instance of the object is not working?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a new instance of a class within the same class and after creating the instance I try to remove the MouseDown listener.

```
package com.objects{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class StickDragDrop extends NumButton {
        public var duplicateObject:MovieClip;
        public function StickDragDrop() {
            init();
        }
        public function init() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,stick);
        }
        public function stick(e:MouseEvent) {
            duplicateObject=new e.currentTarget.constructor
            addChild(duplicateObject);
            duplicateObject.startDrag();
            duplicateObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,stick);
            duplicateObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,unStick);
        }
        public function unStick(e:MouseEvent) {
            stopDrag();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what are you trying to achieve, please? First, I can't understand why are you adding duplicate object to target object?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove an Event Listener for `duplicateObject` that would call `this.stick`, not `duplicateObject.stick` and that event listener doesn't exist.

Try adding:

```
public function removeStick() {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,stick)
}
```

to your class, and instead of calling

```
duplicateObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,stick);
```

call

```
duplicateObject.removeStick();
```

---

Alternatively, you probably could just change the call to

```
duplicateObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,duplicateObject.stick);
```

But I prefer the first option.